# Получаю всегда ноль при обращении к любому индексу

Tags: java

Получаю всегда ноль при обращении к любому индексу.

Код.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Arr = {"1", "2", "3"};

        int[] Res = ElementsToList(Arr);

        System.out.println(Res[0]);
    }

    public static int[] ElementsToList(String[] Elements) {
        int[] Converted = new int[Elements.length];

        for(int i = 0; i == Elements.length; i++) {
            Converted[i] = Integer.parseInt(Elements[i]);
        }

        return Converted;
    }
}
```

Что я пытался сделать? Конвертировать все строки в массиве, в число.

При обращение к любому индексу в Res, получаю 0.
Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
                 ^
```

Это условие *продолжения* (а не остановки) цикла.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Justadude... Пожалуйста. Успехов.